# Can't aggregate a DecimalField in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset where I want to aggregate the fields `amount` which itself is a DecimalField. The target field is also a DecimalField.

I get this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["“{'amount__sum': Decimal('3821.02000000000')}” value must be a decimal number."]

Why does it say it must be a decimal number even though it is a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield)?

```
# models.py

class Payment(models.Model):

    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payroll_run = models.ForeignKey(Payroll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)  # is populated once the payroll run was created

    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)


class Payroll(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    line_items = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

```
def test():
   ...

    # Loop the companies
    for company in qs_companies:
        # Query all Payments of that company in that month
        qs_payments = Payment.objects.filter(offer__company=company).filter(month=period)

        # Create a payroll run instance
        payroll_run = Payroll.objects.create(
            company=company,
            month=next_payroll_run,
            amount=qs_payments.aggregate(Sum('amount')),
            line_items=qs_payments.count()
        )

        payroll_run.save()
   ...
```

Comment: What do you do that causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) returns a dictionary, you need to pass your aggregated value and not the whole dict

```
        payroll_run = Payroll.objects.create(
            company=company,
            month=next_payroll_run,
            amount=qs_payments.aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'], # <- added the lookup
            line_items=qs_payments.count()
        )
```

EDIT: From Django 4.0 [you can add a `default` argument to `Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#default)

```
amount=qs_payments.aggregate(Sum('amount', default=Decimal(0)))['amount__sum']
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It now returns `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: company_payroll.amount` though even though the qs_payments queryset is not empty. Hmm

Comment: @JSRB That sounds like a new question. Please post it as one with the relevant parts of your current code along with the new error message.

Comment: Nvm my bad, it was caused by the second iteration which had an empty qs indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @JSRB you can add a default argument to `Sum` from Django 4.0 onwards as detailed above